# Using geom_bar with fill where the same fill color is grouped together

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I do the following in R, I get a very strange bar chart

```
a <- c('A', 'B','C','A','B', 'A','C')
b <- rep(2015, 7)
c <- c(5, 32, 7, 1, 74, 2, 23)
d <- data.frame(a,b,c)
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=b, y=c, fill=a)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I get the following chart
[image]

I have 3 red areas instead of one, 2 green areas and 2 blue areas.

Why does the same color not add up to one single area?

Comment: what value do you expect to correspond to the "single area"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ggplot determines the stacking order based on the order of your data. So you can summarize your data like @Mateusz1981 did, but another approach is to sort your data by your fill variable by using order:

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=factor(b), y=c, fill=a, order=a)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

directly

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=factor(b), y=c, fill = factor(a))) + stat_summary(fun.y = sum, aes(group = a), geom = "bar", position = "stack")
```

or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    d <- d %>%  group_by(a, b) %>% summarise(s = sum(c))
    ggplot(data=d, aes(x=factor(b), y=s, fill=a)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]